# I’m smelling gas from my dryer

Tags: dryer, appliances, natural-gas

[image][image][image]This gas dryer was previously sitting in an old storage unit for many years before I decided to take it out and run it again. I’m very inexperienced with dryers so as you’ll see in the hookup that there’s a lot of excess venting and then also a lot of different fittings used in order to match the Diameter of the gas line. I know all of these things need to be fixed. A long time ago (over a year ) I had a professional come and take a look at it because it wasn’t drying the clothes all the way, I could also smell gas. He did a few test on the timing clock because it’s a coin operated system. (It was shutting off too early in the heating cycle). He didn’t seem to have any problems with the clock not working but he eventually went down to the gas value and realized that the gas could be coming out of there. He said that the gas value is very expensive and I might be better off just buying another drying machine. I cannot remember if it was the gas value that was leaking gas or if that was just up in the air as a possible cause. Here I am 1 year later trying to solve the problem( oh how time gets away :() Im wondering where I should start in this process. Im going to fix the vent pipe and fitting problems today but as for the short cycling (I don’t know if this is the right definition, but the cycling stopping short of the clothes being dry) and then the smell of gas. I don’t know where to start.

Please let me know if you have additional questions about the problem. I’m going to be regularly checking this forum to make sure I preform and test anyone has for me to do. Thank you [image]

Make of dryer - whirlpool
Model number of dryer - CGM2751KQ3
Serial number - MS0901511
Type - BDOT-NAT-CS22

Link to the gas value part on partselect

https://www.partselect.com/PS334359-Whirlpool-279923-Gas-Valve-Kit.htm?SourceCode=3&SearchTerm=8281911

Comment: I do not know what a new dryer will cost these days, but spending ~240 dollars plus still not having the timer maybe not work right, plus maybe other problems does not seem good, plus you always need to make sure you have money handy(even if you get it back).

Comment: First, turn off the gas and ventilate the area well. No light switches or sparks until you can’t smell gas anymore. Get some gas leak detector fluid and find out where the leak is. That’ll at least verify what needs work.

Comment: If this is in a rental (suggested by the coin-op) DIY’ing gas work is likely illegal.

Comment: Even more strongly suggested by the locks being on the coin-op. I've seen semi-retired commercial coin-ops installed in a home with the locks off, and you just keep the appropriate change in there to start it with, and put it right back in - but having the lock on carries the implication that someone is being charged for using this defective dryer that was stored for a long time rather than being junked when it broke years ago.

Answer (score 3):

STOP and shut off the gas shutoff valve for the yellow supply line (or the whole house if you don't have one). Leaving gas leaking is how buildings burn down or even explode.

Seems like you don't have much or any experience working with gas lines/fittings/appliances. For example, there are important rules for types of fittings and features such as "drip legs". Better off to just "declare victory and retreat" :) and have this dryer (or a new one) fixed/installed by someone who knows how to work with gas.

Comment: Fire department advice here is "If you smell gas when you don't expect to, LEAVE THE BUILDING IMMEDIATELY WITHOUT TOUCHING ANY SWITCHES, AND CALL FROM ELSEWHERE FOR ASSISTANCE." Gas _looks_ easy, and conceptually is easy ... but the consequences of getting it wrong can be catastrophic, so it really isn't a good choice for DIY.